# Splitting a list into sublists with different sizes

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list `{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}` and would like to split it into a list of size 2, a list of size 3, and covert the remaining element  into singleton lists, giving the result `{{7, 8}, {9, 10, 11}, {12}, {13}, {14}}`. Is there a built-in function that allows me to do this?

Comment: `FoldPairList[TakeDrop, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {2, 3, 1, 1, 1}]` or  ```Internal`PartitionRagged[{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {2, 3, 1, 1, 
  1}]``` - usual caution re: undocumented/internal functions.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! Could you tell me what is the exact action of FoldPairList? I am reading the documentation but don't really understand the explanations and the examples. Thanks!

Comment: If the solutions in the linked question do not suit you, please edit your question to say why they don't work for you.